# Which Pokémon are exclusive to each version?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

I would like to complete my Pokédex, but I don't know which Pokémon I can find specifically in the wild on my Moon version and which I can't. What Pokémon are exclusive to each one of the two versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is indeed some Pokémon that you can't catch in the wild if you are on a specific version (aside of the fact that you can obtain them with trading of course). Here is the list of the Pokémon you can find specifically on each version and not on the other:

Pokémon Sun:

- [Braviary](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Braviary_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Buzzwole](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Buzzwole_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Carracosta](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Carracosta_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Cottonee](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cottonee_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Cranidos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Cranidos_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Kartana](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Kartana_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Ninetales](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ninetales_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Passimian](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Passimian_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Rampardos](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rampardos_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Rufflet](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Rufflet_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Solgaleo](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Solgaleo_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Tirtouga](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tirtouga_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Turtonator](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Turtonator_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Vulpix](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vulpix_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Whimsicott](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Whimsicott_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

Pokémon Moon:

- [Archen](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Archen_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Archeops](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Archeops_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Bastiodon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Bastiodon_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Celesteela](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Celesteela_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Drampa](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Drampa_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Lilligant](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lilligant_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Lunala](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lunala_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Mandibuzz](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Mandibuzz_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Oranguru](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oranguru_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Petilil](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Petilil_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Pheromosa](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pheromosa_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Sandshrew](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sandshrew_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Sandslash](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sandslash_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Shieldon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shieldon_(Pok%C3%A9mon))
- [Vullaby](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Vullaby_(Pok%C3%A9mon))

Comment: Which way around is the list, is this the list of Pokémon not available in that respective version, or is it the list of Pokémon that can be found in that version?

Comment: It's the list of Pokémon only available on the respective version. I modified the answer to make it more clear.